# access same subnet on different interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing, router, nat

**I have a router with external (WAN connection) subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and also on same router a tunnel to a remote location which have the exact same subnet (192.168.1.0/24), and i need from my LAN to access the remote location computers !**

I was thinking about a firewall to change any traffic over the tunnel interface from 192.168.1.0/24 to let's just say 192.168.51.0/24, so from my local network if I try to access any IP from 192.168.51.0/24 I will get responses from the remote network, but I can't figure out how to do that :(

as first answer, yes I should mention that operating system is Linux and tunnel is pppoe

PS I apologize about my English and formulation, is second time when I have edit the question with the hope that now is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what operating system you are using, but assuming Linux, this might be as simple as creating a route entry for each network you need to access via the interface that is your endpoint of the tunnel.

For example, if the interface you are using to connect you to the tunnel is tap0, this **might** work:

```
ip route add 192.168.51.0/24 dev tap0
```

There are a lot of additional details that would be helpful in solving this, such as, operating system, and what type of tunnel you are using. Based on the information supplied, and some limited testing this is the best answer I can provide right now.

I'd would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet :)

Comment: ofc I did that from start, I cannot put twice the same "192.168.1.1/24" on a tcp/ip machine and both work in the same time, so I need something to translate 192.168.51.0/24 to "192.168.1.0/24"

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood the question then.  Are you trying to reach a subnet with the address space of 192.168.1.0/24 that is accessible through the tunnel which has an address space of 192.168.1.0/24?  Otherwise, I'm not sure why adding a route out the interface wouldn't do it.  I'll test it and see what I can do.

Are there any additional details you can give here?  If the other end is a pppoe tunnel, is this a DSL connection?  Does the DSL provider have an address space of 192.168.1.0/24 on the other end?

Comment: I put corrections on the main question, just to be sure everyone can see it